# determine item state of a grid WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have the following two methods in my model, the "AddSelectedItemGrid" method will add selected items to the grid and the "LoadDataGrid" will load the data into the grid. I want to add a new method that saves the newly added items in the grid, but i dont know how to determine which items are newly added or edited. How can i get the rowstate to determine which items i need to save.

## Model

### to add items to grid

```
    public void AddSelectedItemGrid(object Parameter)
    {
        if (Parameter != null)
        {
            string test1 = ((Test.SharedLib.Data.testSubBO)(Parameter)).Term;
            Int64 test2 = Convert.ToInt64(((testSubBO)(Parameter)).ComputerId);

            ComputerDataGridListTest.Add(new ComputerDataGridBO()
            {
                Term = test1,
                ComputerId = test2
            });
        }
    }
```

### Load grid from db

```
public void LoadDataGrid()
{
    int testp = 443;
    DataTable m_ComputerDataGrid;

    DataSet ds = test.SharedLib.Application.WebService.ExecuteQuery("[emr_selecttest2]", new SPParam[] {
    new SPParam("@ComputerId", testp) });

    m_ComputerDataGrid = ds.Tables[0];

    ComputerDataGridListTest = new List<ComputerDataGridBO>();

    foreach (DataRow r in m_ComputerDataGrid.Rows)
    {
        ComputerDataGridListTest.Add(new ComputerDataGridBO()
        {
            ComputerId = Convert.ToInt64(r["ConceptId"].ToString()),
            Term = r["Term"].ToString()
        });
    }
}
```

### ComputerDataGridBO

```
class ComputerDataGridBO
{
    public Int64 ComputerId { get; set; }
    public string Term { get; set; }

}
```

### List

```
public List<ComputerDataGridBO> ComputerDataGridListTest { get; set; }
```

Comment: why don't you just add a boolean flag to ComputerDataGridBO?

Comment: can you provide a example

Comment: It seems Sheridan has already provided an example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do what you want. You *could* keep a record of the items that you add into the collection. In MVVM, we work with the *data* and we don't generally need to manipulate any *UI elements* to find out these things:

```
public List<ComputerDataGridBO> ItemsToSave { get; set; }

public void AddSelectedItemGrid(object Parameter)
{
    if (Parameter != null)
    {
        string test1 = ((Test.SharedLib.Data.testSubBO)(Parameter)).Term;
        Int64 test2 = Convert.ToInt64(((testSubBO)(Parameter)).ComputerId);

        ComputerDataGridBO newItem = new ComputerDataGridBO()
        {
            Term = test1,
            ComputerId = test2
        };
        ItemsToSave.Add(newItem);
        ComputerDataGridListTest.Add(newItem);
    }
}
```

Then you just need to save the `ItemsToSave` collection. To handle editing, you could implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and then handle the `PropertyChanged` event to find out when an item property had been changed and therefore whether or not to add that item to the `ItemsToSave` collection.

Alternatively, as @Bizz mentioned, you could add a `bool IsEdited` property to the `ComputerDataGridBO` class that you could set to `true` whenever an instance is created, or a property is changed. You could do that from inside the class (of course, you'd need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface to make this work):

```
public bool IsEdited { get; set; }
public string Term 
{
    get { return term; }
    set { term = value; IsEdited = true; } // Do for each property
}
```

Or you could also do it using a [`DataGrid.CurrentCellChanged` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.currentcellchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) handler attached to the `DataGrid`, although that would be a less MVVM method of achieving this functionality. Either way, you could then use `LinQ` to find the altered and new items when you want to save them:

```
List<ComputerDataGridBO> itemsToSave = new List<ComputerDataGridBO>(
    ComputerDataGridListTest.Where(c => c.IsEdited));
if (itemsToSave != null)
{
    // save items in itemsToSave and set their IsEdited properties to false
}
```

Of course, there are more sophisticated ways of doing this, but I'm guessing that you've got the overall picture now.